# In R, how do I show a decimal point only when the number is not a whole number?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting some data, with xticks that have both whole and unwhole numbers. My x-axis looks like this:
[image]

This is the axis code I used: `scale_x_reverse(breaks = round(seq(100,0,by = -100/6),digits = 1))`.

My goal is to only show the decimal point when it's needed i.e when the number is not whole. In my example it would mean removing the '.0' after 100 and 50, while leaving the decimal points of the other ticks.

Comment: Something like `gsub("\\.0$", "", as.character(round(seq(100,0,by = -100/6),digits = 1)))`?

Comment: @teunbrand Brilliant! that worked perfectly. Defined it as the labels: `scale_x_reverse(breaks = round(seq(100,0,by = -100/6),digits = 1), labels = gsub("\\.0$", "", as.character(round(seq(100,0,by = -100/6),digits = 1))))`

Comment: To reduce code duplication, you can probably go even further and provide a function to the `labels` argument: `scale_x_reverse(breaks = round(seq(100,0,by = -100/6),digits = 1), 
                labels = function(x){gsub("\\.0$", "", as.character(x))})`.